# (simple) find value of m which makes a quadratic function continuous on R, please add explanation for the discriminant usage

Tags: calculus

I need explanation on the usage of the discriminant  $b^2 - 4ac$ to answer this question please.

If $$f(x) = \frac{(x+3)}{(x^2 + mx +9)}$$ is continuous on $\Re$, then $m$  $\epsilon$ ........

Comment: What have you tried? Consider asking yourself where a function of this form could possibly fail to be continuous.

Comment: **Hint:**

Notice that $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ iff $x^2+mx+9\neq0$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: It fails if $x^2 + mx + 9 = 0$

Comment: I know that but i want the solution steps to find the range of m where the function will fail

Comment: The answer is written as $ ]-6 , 6 [ $  but trying to check with $ m = 5 $ it turns out that $x ∈ Z$

Comment: By using the discriminant of a quadratic polynomial the problem reduces to solving the quadratic inequality $m^2-4\cdot 9<0$, which solution set is indeed $]-6,6[$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with $g(x)=x^2+mx+9$ for $x\in\Bbb R$, then look for the zeroes of $g$:

$$x={-m\pm\sqrt{m^2-36}\over 2}$$

If $|m|\ge 6$ then the zeroes of $g$ are real numbers.  If not, then $g$ has no real zeroes.  In particular, the discriminant, the value $b^2-4ac = m^2-36$ is the deciding factor in this problem, since we take the square root of $m^2-36$.  If $m^2-36$ is negative, i.e. $m^2 \lt 36$, the square root introduces non-real solutions, which is another way of saying that $g(x)$ never crosses the zero line ($g(x)=0$).  Can you continue from here?

Comment: so final answer would be $ R - ]-6,6[$ or i am understanding something wrongly?

Comment: No, the final answer would just be $m\in]-6,6[$, since $|m|\ge 6$ causes discontinuities to exist.  Specifically, $7\in \Bbb R\setminus ]-6,6[$, but $m=7$ causes real zeroes to exist in the denominator of $f(x)$.

Comment: Yeah... got it ... I was thinking about that if m was = 4 .. it gives real number forgetting about that means the equation = zero in that case ... my mind was spinning a little sorry  thanks 